# Duplicate elements in a list to have the same length as number of elements in a second list

Tags: r, list

I'm using rvest to scrape the comments of some blog posts and the belonging title of the article/ blog post to which the comments belong.
The scraping itself worked out just fine but now I would like to assign the title of the blog post and the comments to one data frame.
Of course, most blog post have multiple comments, so it should look like this:

```
title_of_articleA     comment1
title_of_articleA     comment2
title_of_articleA     comment3
title_of_articleA     comment4
title_of_articleB     comment1
title_of_articleB     comment2
```

Basically so that I can later easily see which comments belong to which post.

My problem is however that I currently have two lists (one for the titles, the other one for the comments) with different lengths.
Before I can use unlist() and combine them, I would therefore somehow need to duplicate the elements of each sublist A in order to match the number of items in the related sublist of B.

```
listA<-list("title_of_article 1", "title of article 2")
listB<-list(c("comment 1" ,"comment 2", "comment 3", "comment 4"), c("comment 1", "comment2"))
```

I can use sapply(listB, length) to receive indicators for how many elements I need, but how do I use that information to tell ListA to duplicate it's items accordingly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
set_names(listB, listA) %>% 
      enframe %>% 
      unnest
# A tibble: 6 x 2
#  name               value    
#  <chr>              <chr>    
#1 title_of_article 1 comment 1
#2 title_of_article 1 comment 2
#3 title_of_article 1 comment 3
#4 title_of_article 1 comment 4
#5 title of article 2 comment 1
#6 title of article 2 comment 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Set names of `listB` to `unlist(listA)` and then `stack` the result

```
stack(setNames(listB, unlist(listA)))
#     values                ind
#1 comment 1 title_of_article 1
#2 comment 2 title_of_article 1
#3 comment 3 title_of_article 1
#4 comment 4 title_of_article 1
#5 comment 1 title of article 2
#6 comment 2 title of article 2
```

**data**

```
listA <- list("title_of_article 1", "title of article 2")
listB <- list(c("comment 1" , "comment 2", "comment 3", "comment 4"), c("comment 1", "comment 2"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea using `mapply`,

```
do.call(rbind, mapply(cbind, listA, listB))
#     [,1]                 [,2]       
#[1,] "title_of_article 1" "comment 1"
#[2,] "title_of_article 1" "comment 2"
#[3,] "title_of_article 1" "comment 3"
#[4,] "title_of_article 1" "comment 4"
#[5,] "title of article 2" "comment 1"
#[6,] "title of article 2" "comment 2"
```